# Training a RNN/LSTM model got KeyError equal to the val of the length

Tags: python, pandas, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Trying to train this model

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_s = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_s = scaler.transform(X_test)

length = 60
n_features = X_train_s.shape[1]
batch_size = 1

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max', verbose = 1, patience = 5)

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(data = X_train_s, 
                                targets = Y_train[['TARGET_KEEP_LONG', 
                                                   'TARGET_KEEP_SHORT', 
                                                   'TARGET_STAY_FLAT']], 
                                length = length, 
                                batch_size = batch_size)


RNN_model = Sequential()
RNN_model.add(LSTM(180, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (length, n_features)))
RNN_model.add(Dense(3))
RNN_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')

validation_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(data = X_test_s, 
                                           targets = Y_test[['TARGET_KEEP_LONG', 
                                                             'TARGET_KEEP_SHORT', 
                                                             'TARGET_STAY_FLAT']], 
                                           length = length, 
                                           batch_size = batch_size)


RNN_model.fit(generator, 
              epochs=20, 
              validation_data = validation_generator,
              callbacks = [early_stop])
```

I get the error "KeyError: 60" where actually 60 is the value of the variable "length" (if I change it, the error changes accordingly).

The shapes of the training dataset are

```
X_test_s.shape
(114125, 89)
```

same for X_train_s.shape as well as n_features == 89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was exhausting to find the cause due to the poor and misleading error message. Anyway, the trouble was on the target data set form, the TimeseriesGenerator does not accept panda dataframes, just np.arrays. Therefore this

```
 generator = TimeseriesGenerator(data = X_train_s, 
                                targets = Y_train[['TARGET_KEEP_LONG', 'TARGET_KEEP_SHORT',                                                    'TARGET_STAY_FLAT']], length = length, batch_size = batch_size)
```

shall have been written as

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train_s, pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(Y_train[['TARGET_KEEP_LONG', 'TARGET_KEEP_SHORT', 'TARGET_STAY_FLAT']]), length=length, batch_size=batch_size)
```

in the case of just one target, it was enough

```
 generator = TimeseriesGenerator(data = X_train_s, targets = Y_train['TARGET_KEEP_LONG'], length = length, batch_size = batch_size)
```

just one level of squared brackets, not two.